# Delete specific row from pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, pivot-table

I have a 2 tables (Gifts, Campaigns) that both have BelongstoMany relation:

**Relations:**

Campaign relation:

```
public function gifts(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Gift::class, 'campaign_gift');
    }
```

Gift relation:

```
public function campaign(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Campaign::class, 'campaign_gift');
    }
```

I am trying to delete a specific row from a pivot table, but with my current implementation, it deletes all of the rows, that have matching id's. Important note, that a single campaign can have multiple same gift, therefore, gift's id can be repeated within the same campaign, making the table having duplicate records.

Example of a pivot table:

[image: pivot table]

**Current Controller:**

```
function deleteGiftsFromCampaign($id)
    {
        $gift = Gift::find($id);
        $gift -> campaign() -> detach();
        return back();
    }
```

Is there a way to implement a specific row deletion, without creating extra columns within the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $gift = Gift::find($id);
 $gift -> campaign()->detach($gift_id);
```

Comment: Thank you! May you clarify, from where or how should I pass this $gift_id variable into this function? Which exact gift_id should it take? As of now, it is not defined.

Comment: $gift_id is a your gift table's id

Comment: With this implementation, no gifts are being deleted at all :/

Comment: @Hoolis $gift= Gift::find($id);
$gift->campaign()->wherePivot('gift_id','=',$gift_id)->detach();

Comment: the first code work if u have on record try this code ,its work for me

Comment: The issue here, is that there is multiple same entries within the database, for example gift_id 1 and campaign_id 1, and deleting this specific entry, deletes all of the records within this pivot table, that have the gift_id = 1, therefore, searching for a way to delete specific row without implementing extra column for id. As for your implementation, the given $id is matching the $gift_id, non the less, it simply does not delete any records this way.

Comment: @NavalHor Your mentioned code, still deletes all of the records from the pivot table, that matches the gift_id record. And it also deletes it from all campaigns at once.